# Adding number in top left corner of Div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to add a number to the top left corner of my div's, but whatever I have tried so far has not worked properly.

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

Here is what I would like:

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
#Office365, #OneDrive {
   height: 100px;
   width: 16.259%;
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="firstAppRow">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="Office365" style="padding-top: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
        <span>1</span>
        <div><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/OVbiWcG.png" height="50px" width="50px" />
        <p>Office365</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="OneDrive" style="padding-top: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
        <div><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/wJAtQYP.png" height="40px" width="40px" />
        <p>OneDrive</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the numbers in your code.

Comment: @showdev, I took the numbers out because they weren't aligning up at all. So I tried adding them between the divs, and it didn't work.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents taking a look through your history it seems like you comment on lots of answers, but rarely are they upvoted. You should take more time to upvote answers which provide you value to ensure that you're giving back to those who are giving their time to you. In addition make sure that you check the answers that actually provide the solution.

Comment: @Mathias Sorry man! I'll be upvoting answers now, I haven't fully grasped this concept on stackoverflow.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents All good, all of your questions are well written and provide the necessary code -- make sure you click the checkmark on answers that solved your problem!

Comment: @Mathias Will do bud! Thanks again for your help on my other question, I'm still tackling the white space issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He, the solution will be to use absolute position for the numbers.
Note that the blocks containing the tag with the number will need to be positioned relative so that the numbers are absolute to that block. Here is a sample code

```css
 #Office365,#OneDrive{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;

    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding: 0 50px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #Office365 img,#OneDrive img{
    width:100px;
    height: auto;
    }

    .num{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="row" id="firstAppRow">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="Office365" style="padding-top: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
        <div><img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/office-365.png" height="50px" width="50px" />
        <p>Office365</p>
          <span class="num">1</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="OneDrive" style="padding-top: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
        <div><img src="https://bcpsodl.pbworks.com/f/1477585037/onedrive.png" height="40px" width="40px" />
        <p>OneDrive</p>
          <span class="num">2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sagwadi, all I needed was the .num css class and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning

```
position: relative;
```

to the #Office365 and #OneDrive. Also put the images inside those divs.

Then assign

```
position: absolute;
left: 1px;
top: 1px;
```

to #Office365 span and #OneDrive span.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Gregor, I figured it out :D

Answer (score 0):

absolute vs float

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-right:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.viaAbsolute {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.viaFloat {
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <span class="viaAbsolute">
    1
  </span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempus rhoncus quam quis vestibulum. Cras eu mollis nisl. Pellentesque semper tincidunt placerat.
</div>

<div class="a">
  <span class="viaFloat">
    1
  </span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempus rhoncus quam quis vestibulum. Cras eu mollis nisl. Pellentesque semper tincidunt placerat.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @fnostro, I got it figured out :D

Comment: I noticed :)  I just wanted to chime in with a flow comparison between float and absolute.  Happy Programming